# How to highlight content ng2 pdf viewer in angular

Tags: angular

I am having trouble highlighting the content of pdf files with an array of tags available in Angular Cli
Or converting to html then I can replace it to highlight.
I am using ng2-pdf-viewer.
Hope everybody help please.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome aboard! Interesting question, but we need you to include more details. What are your expected and actual results? Do you have any error messages your seeing? Describe the things you've already tried and, most importantly, show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pdf-viewer *ngIf="isPdf" #pdfViewer id="pdfViewer" name="pdfViewer" [src]="pdfSrc.url"
                                [render-text]="true" [show-borders]="false" [autoresize]="true"
                                (on-progress)="onProgress($event)" (error)="onError($event)" [zoom]="1"
                                [show-all]="true" (after-load-complete)="afterLoadComplete($event)"
                                [original-size]="false" [(page)]="page" [stick-to-page]="true"
                                (text-layer-rendered)="textLayerRendered($event)" [external-link-target]="'blank'"
                                style="display: block;"
                                </pdf-viewer>

<ng-container *ngFor="let page of remainingPdfPages; let i = index">
                                <canvas class="pdf-page" [attr.page]="i + 1"></canvas>
                                <div class="pdf-page-div" [attr.page]="i + 1">{{i+1}}</div>
                            </ng-container>
```

Comment: At ng-container I want show textLayer all page pdf  so I can highlight html,  removed canvas pdf